# customvalidator client side validation

Tags: javascript, customvalidator

I have a custom validator and want it to validate client side on not server side.
Here is my function :

```
function checkCampDockTemplate(source, args)
    {
        var campDockTemplate = document.getElementById('<%= drpCampDockTemplate.ClientID %>');

        if (campDockTemplate.selectedIndex == 0)
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }



<asp:CustomValidator ID="campaignDocketTemplateCustomValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please select a Campaign Docket Template"
            ControlToValidate="drpCampDockTemplate" OnServerValidate="campaignDocketTemplateCustomValidator_ServerValidate"
            ClientValidationFunction="javascript:checkCampDockTemplate()"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Can any one please assist me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the format of the function mostly correct, but you need to reference the client-side function by name only in the `ClientValidationFunction` attribute, e.g.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="campaignDocketTemplateCustomValidator" 
runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="Please select a Campaign Docket Template"
ControlToValidate="drpCampDockTemplate"     
OnServerValidate="campaignDocketTemplateCustomValidator_ServerValidate"
ClientValidationFunction="checkCampDockTemplate"/>
```

If you also want to remove the server-side validation completely, you can remove the `OnServerValidate` attribute from the CustomValidator.

Generally speaking though, it's usually wise to validate your input on the server as well as on the client side, in case people have javascript turned off!